# How to reshape dataframe from long to wide across several variables?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr, reshape2, magrittr

[image: This is an image of my dataset after following a users suggestion, it corresponds to follow up 1.]I have a data set that looks a bit like this, except very long:

```
 treatment  biomass greenness height    NDVI
1 Apigenin 0.001 221694.0   0.15028 92.647 0.21001
2 Apigenin 0.001  72639.6   0.22868 90.435 0.22735
3 Apigenin 0.001 232935.0   0.19238 84.684 0.29084
4 Apigenin 0.001 199267.0   0.23515 95.618 0.28140
5 Apigenin 0.001 213989.0   0.21403 86.819 0.31824
6 Apigenin 0.001 143787.0   0.19836 99.779 0.25108
```

I would like to convert format it to get 4 different data frames - 1 dataframe/independant vairbale (biomassdata, greennessdata, heightdata, NDVIdata) that have each treatment as a column and the values of the measurement as measurements.

This is what I have done - I basically break up the data set into separate data frames first, and then tried to both spread. It didn't work --  I can't get it to consider all the same repeated treatments as 1.

I want it to put all the biomass readings for all Apigenin 0.001 (6 different biomass readings) in an "Apigenin 0.001" column.

```
 biomassdata <- data[c(1,2)]
 head(biomassdata)

treatment  biomass
1 Apigenin 0.001 221694.0
2 Apigenin 0.001  72639.6
3 Apigenin 0.001 232935.0
4 Apigenin 0.001 199267.0
5 Apigenin 0.001 213989.0
6 Apigenin 0.001 143787.0

data_wide <- spread(data, treatment, biomass)

**my error**

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 24 rows:
* 61, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90
```

Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Follow up 1: I nurandi's suggestion and added an ID column + ran what they had written and I get a staggered data frame like this. Even after using na.omit, I can't get rid of the NAs. How could I collapse this so that all the data as a 6 rows x nth columns df?

Follow up 2: Here is my data with the **dput(data)**

```
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("Apigenin 0.001", "Apigenin 0.01", 
"Apigenin 0.1", "Apigenin 1", "Apigenin 10", "Arbutin 0.001", 
"Arbutin 0.01", "Arbutin 0.1", "Arbutin 1", "Arbutin 10", "blank", 
"Catechin 0.001", "Catechin 0.01", "Catechin 0.1", "Catechin 1", 
"Catechin 10", "Control 0", "Epicatechin 0.001", "Epicatechin 0.01", 
"Epicatechin 0.1", "Epicatechin 1", "Epicatechin 10"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = 1:162, biomass = c(221694, 72639.6, 232935, 199267, 
    213989, 143787, 108455, 147839, 252471, 142101, 119912, 227052, 
    178779, 43711.7, 276519, 176843, 159333, 154074, 59773.9, 
    59487.9, 88314.4, 93913, 216126, 179190, 204302, 290455, 
    121592, 132088, 135095, 184920, 142149, 163629, 148910, 93512.5, 
    27448.5, 89122.8, 121462, 122664, 113559, 175693, 156794, 
    152504, 253416, 151476, 296591, 204390, 350047, 280300, 245592, 
    131444, 209276, 156653, 187770, 135809, 115277, 158624, 171040, 
    146898, 204402, 69558.6, 0, 13606.8, 0, 0, 95.986, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 10117.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 390.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4551.37, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62.509, 0, 0, 0, 191794, 144348, 156837, 133628, 
    100955, 141259, 194590, 88728.2, 254885, 217073, 149569, 
    140578, 239332, 123793, 117182, 128033, 288146, 124335, 50298.3, 
    58042, 271309, 76837.5, 64283.4, 39683.5, 143766, 246305, 
    222373, 104302, 135446, 211847, 170214, 167940, 190325, 266613, 
    154118, 161985, 212837, 107061, 251746, 174159, 221187, 92178, 
    259297, 127482, 284857, 108563, 277292, 122333, 327831, 198009, 
    225756, 204637, 223356, 196766, 117736, 160845, 263906, 132815, 
    443663, 157005, 190361, 176090, 215908, 203894, 171227, 201593, 
    146864, 130770, 99702.7, 228162, 202906, 233314), greenness = c(0.15028, 
    0.22868, 0.19238, 0.23515, 0.21403, 0.19836, 0.2237, 0.17761, 
    0.23665, 0.24452, 0.2126, 0.20856, 0.1506, 0.23842, 0.16838, 
    0.20856, 0.19131, 0.21226, 0.21069, 0.13162, 0.22843, 0.18827, 
    0.2189, 0.20778, 0.17662, 0.23778, 0.14829, 0.19675, 0.19279, 
    0.20615, 0.16436, 0.19543, 0.19704, 0.20855, 0.13348, 0.23248, 
    0.19071, 0.2136, 0.20921, 0.17778, 0.19822, 0.21325, 0.16728, 
    0.25961, 0.17343, 0.20308, 0.17734, 0.242, 0.22057, 0.16954, 
    0.19165, 0.1845, 0.17033, 0.20429, 0.16552, 0.25312, 0.19969, 
    0.21126, 0.21567, 0.20092, 0, 0.15785, 0, 0, 0.06892, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.18583, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.18747, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03289, 0, 0, 0, 0.1896, 0.27279, 0.16916, 
    0.2194, 0.19494, 0.20371, 0.24688, 0.2282, 0.22256, 0.21988, 
    0.22612, 0.20273, 0.21205, 0.2467, 0.17265, 0.25261, 0.20605, 
    0.24522, 0.23485, 0.20824, 0.21689, 0.20503, 0.21646, 0.19256, 
    0.18349, 0.25014, 0.21185, 0.21199, 0.19043, 0.22531, 0.19896, 
    0.23486, 0.20735, 0.20261, 0.17726, 0.22984, 0.23568, 0.21472, 
    0.20697, 0.2529, 0.23796, 0.17527, 0.1892, 0.21681, 0.17071, 
    0.2288, 0.2082, 0.24332, 0.21457, 0.19615, 0.22709, 0.2089, 
    0.21144, 0.25504, 0.17523, 0.21035, 0.19321, 0.24167, 0.21131, 
    0.2185, 0.20862, 0.19959, 0.20922, 0.25067, 0.23803, 0.21703, 
    0.20565, 0.23583, 0.21409, 0.22438, 0.19036, 0.23628), height = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NDVI = c(65.077, 
    71.607, 62.782, 74.981, 67.432, 80.255, 67.415, 59.571, 67.783, 
    70.877, 64.327, 72.559, 60.308, 50.861, 65.375, 62.926, 70.161, 
    76.615, 64.328, 71.278, 57.754, 61.734, 66.04, 57.962, 56.844, 
    70.889, 58.485, 65.606, 61.301, 66.876, 47.079, 73.912, 80.114, 
    59.559, 49.89, 29.104, 60.602, 70.481, 66.94, 72.538, 64.116, 
    60.579, 66.579, 52.237, 71.65, 74.068, 70.205, 61.413, 69.771, 
    65.47, 61.813, 64.855, 73.321, 58.804, 70.393, 57.986, 60.365, 
    69.463, 61.317, 45.124, 0, 63.492, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    29.118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.232, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 67.73, 65.52, 57.589, 65.524, 60.692, 
    75.595, 71.817, 61.508, 72.19, 75.911, 56.581, 63.549, 69.393, 
    63.835, 57.988, 43.169, 71.803, 54.076, 33.243, 77.246, 70.999, 
    58.495, 47.994, 51.257, 70.875, 63.179, 77.211, 63.353, 49.996, 
    72.651, 50.371, 60.6, 66.92, 72.503, 57.064, 52.697, 58.914, 
    59.243, 52.637, 55.861, 68.979, 73.941, 62.623, 72.005, 80.262, 
    41.771, 69.721, 64.639, 81.986, 87.598, 58.017, 66.916, 74.297, 
    71.967, 65.933, 70.657, 60.856, 52.216, 68.772, 69.043, 59.239, 
    69.204, 65.91, 83.655, 62.093, 61.576, 55.245, 56.44, 74.885, 
    70.636, 63.449, 68.166)), row.names = c(NA, -162L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is **dput(head(data,5))**

```
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Apigenin 0.001", 
"Apigenin 0.01", "Apigenin 0.1", "Apigenin 1", "Apigenin 10", 
"Arbutin 0.001", "Arbutin 0.01", "Arbutin 0.1", "Arbutin 1", 
"Arbutin 10", "blank", "Catechin 0.001", "Catechin 0.01", "Catechin 0.1", 
"Catechin 1", "Catechin 10", "Control 0", "Epicatechin 0.001", 
"Epicatechin 0.01", "Epicatechin 0.1", "Epicatechin 1", "Epicatechin 10"
), class = "factor"), ID = 1:5, biomass = c(221694, 72639.6, 
232935, 199267, 213989), greenness = c(0.15028, 0.22868, 0.19238, 
0.23515, 0.21403), height = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NDVI = c(65.077, 
71.607, 62.782, 74.981, 67.432)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is **dput(head(biomassdata,5))**

```
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Apigenin 0.001", 
"Apigenin 0.01", "Apigenin 0.1", "Apigenin 1", "Apigenin 10", 
"Arbutin 0.001", "Arbutin 0.01", "Arbutin 0.1", "Arbutin 1", 
"Arbutin 10", "blank", "Catechin 0.001", "Catechin 0.01", "Catechin 0.1", 
"Catechin 1", "Catechin 10", "Control 0", "Epicatechin 0.001", 
"Epicatechin 0.01", "Epicatechin 0.1", "Epicatechin 1", "Epicatechin 10"
), class = "factor"), ID = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

My expected output is similar to the screenshot except collapsed (i.e. no N/A values.) 
Similar to: 
Apigenin 0.001 <- c(x,y,z,w,s,f)
Apigenin 0.01 <- c(g,h,j,u,t,d)
etc. where the letters are different observations of biomass.

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your data using dput(header(data)) ?

Comment: @user12256545 The first set of code I provided is the head of my dataset :)

Comment: ok consider using dput(), this way others can copy your data way easier and you get your answer even faster

Answer (score 0):

From `tidyr` manual:

> Development on `spread()` is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to `pivot_wider()`, which is easier to use, more featureful, and still under active development.

To reshape long to wide format, your dataframe need one ID or more. This is my suggestion using modified data (I added ID into it).

```
library(tidyr)

biomass_data <- df %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = "treatment", values_from = "biomass")

biomass_data

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      ID Apigenin1 Apigenin2
#   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1     0.001     0.001
# 2     2     0.001     0.001
# 3     3     0.001     0.001


greenness_data <- df %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = "treatment", values_from = "greenness")

greenness_data

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      ID Apigenin1 Apigenin2
#   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1    221694    72640.
# 2     2    232935   199267 
# 3     3    213989   143787
```

Comment: as far as I know, yes. How your data look like? Table is 6 columns, but header only 6

Comment: I updated my question with a follow up - the kind of data frame I get is not clean and has many NA values. How can I tackle this?

Comment: can you please run `dput(head(DF,5))` and put the result into question? (change DF with your dataframe)

Comment: also your expected output

Comment: Done!  Thank you so much for helping me through this.